# Programa pra imprimir uma matriz com o mesmo numero de linhas e colunas com de ordem decrescente

Tags: c++

preciso saber como ficaria um programa para imprimir uma matriz do mesmo modo abaixo, em que a linha de baixo sempre vai subtrair 1 do numero de cima. Eu realmente tentei fazer um código porém não sabia por onde começar, por isso vim pedir um help aqui.

```
 6 5 4 3  \\ Caso o usuário digite 4 linhas
 5 4 3 2
 4 3 2 1
 3 2 1 0


 4 3 2   \\ Caso o usuário digite 3 linhas
 3 2 1 
 2 1 0

 2 1     \\ Caso o usuário digite 2 linhas
 1 0
```

Comment: Coloque o código para imprimir a matriz com os valores zerados, assim conseguimos ajuda-lo sem fazer todo o trabalho.

Comment: Mas em poucas palavras cada valor corresponde a subtração da linha e coluna atuais(começando em 1) do dobro de linhas totais.

Comment: Mas a matriz é toda fornecida pelo usuario ? Ou o usuário fornece apenas o primeiro valor e o tamanho ?

Comment: Opa, pessoal. Muito obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, o código abaixo resolve seu problema.
Seria isso mesmo?

Se necessitar de ajuda para entender o código, basta avisar.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int squareMatrixOrder;
    cout << "Enter the square matrix order: \n";
    cin >> squareMatrixOrder;

    int startNumber = (squareMatrixOrder * 2) - 2;

    for( int row = squareMatrixOrder; row > 0 ; row-- ) {
        int currentNumber = startNumber;
        for( int column = 0; column < squareMatrixOrder; column++ ) {
            cout << currentNumber-- << " ";
        }
        startNumber--;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Caramba, cara!! Isso mesmo, show. Só não entendi bem porque meu professor usa printf, scanf, e pelo fato de estar em inglês, mas fora isso o código é realmente o  que o exercício pedia.

Comment: Faça um esforço para compreender o código.
Pesquise sobre a diferença de cout/cin para printf/scanf.
E se habitue ao inglês, é essencial.

No mais, sucesso!!!